# Will I need a new e-Visa to exit Turkey?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, turkey, passport-stamps, eu-id-card

I traveled to Turkey with my Belgium ID card.

I have lost my ID card and my entry sheet, but I still have my passport with me and want to return to Belgium.

Do I have to apply for new e-visa with my passport?

Will I be allowed to leave without showing my entry sheet?

Comment: Did you report the loss to the police? Did they say anything about how you would leave the country?

Comment: I lost it just yesterday and I'm not leaving any time soon. Do you think I should still report it ?

Comment: Of course.  Loss of an ID card is a serious matter.  If it falls into the wrong hands, it could be misused.  Furthermore, the best way to avoid negative immigration consequences in connection with your lost entry sheet is to report it promptly.  If you just show up at the border without it, who knows how long that will take?  Given that you aren't leaving any time soon, take the opportunity to prepare.

Comment: @phoog "Loss of an ID card is a serious matter. If it falls into the wrong hands, it could be misused" I agree 100%. "If you just show up at the border without it, who knows how long that will take?" Not really, they'll have OP's entry on record, even if their document numbers are different. A grumpy officer might scold OP though for losing it.

Comment: Wayne: for Belgium's requirements in the case of a lost or stolen ID card, see https://www.belgium.be/fr/famille/identite/carte_d_identite/perte_ou_vol for French or https://www.belgium.be/nl/familie/identiteit/identiteitskaart/verlies_of_diefstal for Dutch.

Answer (score 1):

Being that someone I know entered Turkey on their passport and exited on their ID card hassle-free (claiming to have lost the entry form, and getting a new one with only an exit stamp) **you should be fine**. Turkey, unlike most EU countries, records entries and exits electronically.

If you want it confirmed, though, you can always go to the airport and ask to speak to the border police. The higher-ranking officials normally speak some English.

You will **not** need a new E-Visa seeing as they're mainly a prerequisite for entry. Once you got in, you were granted a stay of 90 days, which isn't invalidated just because the travel document tied to it got lost.

Comment: Thanks but what if I want to use bus in a return back to Belgium

Comment: Same thing, it doesn't matter what border police office you go to. A regular police station will be of no use in my experience - in particular, they'll likely have no English-speaker on suty

Comment: But @Wayne *also* lost the ID card -- the document used to procure the entry sheet.  Certainly your experience indicates that there's less cause for worry, especially since Wayne has his passport, but don't you think it would still be safer to go to the police *now?*  (Besides, Wayne may also need the police report to get a replacement ID card.)  A further thought: will the electronic record of entry be located with the passport?  I suppose that it probably can be, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @phoog Like I said, the person concerned (German) entered on his passport at Sarp because the officer was unused to EU IDs and was giving him hassle, and he didn't want to miss the bus. Then he presented his ID at Kapikule for exit, whereby he was asked where his migration card was. He said he lost it, and the officer was like "OK", and gave him a new migration card with an exit stamp. So it's pretty clear that the computers can detect legal entries even if on a different document number from what's presented on exit.

Comment: @phoog Still, I did mention that OP might want to contact the border police at an airport

Comment: @Crazydre Ok.  Are you sure the computer found the record?  Maybe it didn't and the officer just decided that the traveler and his story were credible.  If so, a different officer might make a different determination.

Comment: @phoog It must have, because once at Sabiha Gökcen the computer screen was in an angle where I could see it (this latter case involved myself), and I saw records of entries and exits on my previous ID card, in addition to my entry refusal on my current one